# I want to add textboxes at runtime as and when i click a button in visual studio (C#). How should i do it?

Tags: c#, .net, button, runtime

I want to create a code snippet where, when I press a button, a textbox must appear at a position. This must happen at runtime how many ever times I press the button.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
public void ButtonAddNewTextbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
   textbox.Location = new Point(); // specify position inside the constructor

   Controls.Add(textbox);
}
```

Note: I haven't specified the `X` and `Y` coordinates for the Point object.  You can set these yourself by doing:

```
Point p = new Point();
p.X = 100;
p.Y = 100;
```

These values need to be different for each textbox so they are spaced out correctly.